# What is the use of HA proxy in Spring AMQP while designing RabbitMQ clustering?

Tags: rabbitmq, haproxy, spring-amqp

What is the use of HAProxy in Spring AMQP while designing RabbitMQ clustering? Is that part of Spring AMQP or need to configure external? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to do; Spring-AMQP uses a single connection so, generally, HAProxy wouldn't do anything, unless you are using multiple caching connection factories. It is certainly not "part" of Spring-AMQP; cluster failover is handled by the underlying Rabbit connection factory.

Comment: Hi Russell,
Here, we are planning to use HAProxy as a load balancer for rabbitmq clustered nodes, where it will distribute the new requests to the node based on load. So, I would to know what changes we need make at consumer end?

Comment: What was your final setup in the end?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50094705/failover-with-spring-amqp-and-rabbitmq-ha
This should answer your question